# Unexpected alignment of \aligned formula

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I am writing a school report and can't make the below latex centre or even align left (ideally it would just be normally centred). My preamble contains nothing about alignment and all the rest of the text left aligns normally.

```
 \subsection{Maths}
    \begin{align*}
        F = BIl \\
        F = m \cdot 10^{-3} \cdot g \\
        l = 1.92cm = 0.0192m \\
        gradient = \frac{m}{I} = 0.791 \\
        B = \frac{F}{Il} = \frac{m \cdot 10^{-3} \cdot g}{Il} = gradient \cdot \frac{10^{-3} \cdot g}{l} \\
        gradient = \pgfplotstableregressiona \\
        B = 0.791 \cdot \frac{10^{-3} \cdot 9.81}{0.0192}=0.40042 = 0.400  \mbox{ to  3s.f.}
    \end{align*}
```

Comment: you mark alignment points with `&` usually just before the = you have an align with no alignment specified which isn't strictly an error but is weird (it helps if you make a complete example so people can test the output easily)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle [here is the extended project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fkqwrtmscjrp) . What would you suggest I use instead of align? Really I just want centred multiline equations

Comment: please don't use external links, just fix the posted example to be complete. but here you should use `gather*` not align as you don't want alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`align` is for aligned equations with alignment point marked by `&`, as you have no `&` you just have left hand sides with no right hand side so the block seems aligned right.  Use `gather` for a group of unaligned equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\pgfplotstableregressiona{?}

\begin{document}

align
\begin{align*}
        F &= BIl \\
        F &= m \cdot 10^{-3} \cdot g \\
        l &= 1.92cm = 0.0192m \\
        \mathrm{gradient} &= \frac{m}{I} = 0.791 \\
        B &= \frac{F}{Il} = \frac{m \cdot 10^{-3} \cdot g}{Il} = \mathrm{gradient} \cdot \frac{10^{-3} \cdot g}{l} \\
        \mathrm{gradient} &= \pgfplotstableregressiona \\
        B &= 0.791 \cdot \frac{10^{-3} \cdot 9.81}{0.0192}=0.40042 = 0.400  \mbox{ to  3s.f.}
    \end{align*}

gather
\begin{gather*}
        F = BIl \\
        F = m \cdot 10^{-3} \cdot g \\
        l = 1.92cm = 0.0192m \\
        \mathrm{gradient} = \frac{m}{I} = 0.791 \\
        B = \frac{F}{Il} = \frac{m \cdot 10^{-3} \cdot g}{Il} = \mathrm{gradient} \cdot \frac{10^{-3} \cdot g}{l} \\
        \mathrm{gradient} = \pgfplotstableregressiona \\
        B = 0.791 \cdot \frac{10^{-3} \cdot 9.81}{0.0192}=0.40042 = 0.400  \mbox{ to  3s.f.}
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```